# Move variations under product thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to move the variations under my thumbnails but i'm not sure where to start.. Should i use a hook or a template ?

Here's what i'm trying to do : [image]

Feel free to give me ideas or even a solution if you ever encountered this issue !

Comment: You will need alot of changes since its whole form. You can move entire form under the image like this remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 ); . Or build your own form with desired design.

Comment: For the form with my own design i already use a plugin that transform the variations into something that looks like what i want. I'm just trying to move the form under my thumbnail :)

I'll try to remove and add the action but it seems that the hook "woocommerce_product_thumbnail" doesnt work all the time ?

Comment: I dont understan what you mean by "doesnt work all the time".

Comment: When i say 'doesnt work all the time" i'm refering to this guide to hooks : https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/. Maybe i'm wrong (and i'll be glad to be !). Will test this out tonight !

Comment: "New WooCommerce uses a jQuery product gallery, so the “woocommerce_product_thumbnails” might not work." But the same can refers to might not work for specific theme due to theme overriding hooks. Its tested and works perfectly on storefront so gl :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_product_thumbnails` to add your variation under the thumbnail. you need to remove default `woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart` action hook. try the below code. code will go in your functions.php file.

```
function move_variation_under_thumbnail(){

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
    
    global $product;

    // Enqueue variation scripts.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

    // Get Available variations?
    $get_variations = count( $product->get_children() ) <= apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 30, $product );

    // Load the template.
    wc_get_template(
        'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php',
        array(
            'available_variations' => $get_variations ? $product->get_available_variations() : false,
            'attributes'           => $product->get_variation_attributes(),
            'selected_attributes'  => $product->get_default_attributes(),
        )
    );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'move_variation_under_thumbnail', 10 );
```

**Or** you can do below as **Martin Mirchev** suggested.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 ); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );ommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Too complicated for 2 rows of code...

Comment: Tested your solution, nothing changed. Tested Martin solution, variations just disappear.

Comment: Which theme you are using?

Comment: I'm using Salient :)

Comment: Edit : problem was due to a conflict with a plugin called "Additional Variation Images Gallery for WooCommerce". Deactivating it fixed the issue.